# Change color of highlight bar in Netrw directory listing?

Tags: bash, vim

[image: directory listing]

I'm trying to change the color of the light green bar that you use to select files when in netrw directory listing. How would I go about doing this?

Edit:
Additionally, how do i get the colors in netrw directory listing to match those specified in .dircolors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That "light green bar" is the *cursorline*; you can link it to another color from your *colorscheme* via `:highlight link CursorLine TARGET` (where `TARGET` is one of the groups in `:hi` output), or define a custom highlighting via `:highlight CursorLine ctermbg=... guibg=...`; see `:help highlight-args` for details. Note: This will not just affect the netrw plugin, but any use of cursorline within Vim. As you didn't recognize this element, it seems that you're not using it yet, so you should be fine :-)

Alternatively, you could also turn off this plugin feature, via `:let g:netrw_cursor = 0`. See `:help g:netrw_cursor`.

---

The netrw plugin detects certain special files, but the recognized types are different from *dircolors*. You'll find the highlight groups under `:help g:netrw_special_syntax`. Again, you can customize those via `:highlight` commands, as outlined above.

All of these tweaks have to be put into your `~/.vimrc` file, and Vim has to be restarted to see the effects.

Comment: Excellent answer